# How to get changed file name in laravel 4 with plupload?

Tags: php, laravel, plupload

I am new to laravel. I try to upload image by using plupload + laravel 4. I can change the file name but I want to have that changed file name to save in the database. How could I do it please?

At my `vendor/forjuth/plupload/src/Plupload/UploadHandler.php`

I added `time()` to avoid overwrite

```
  $result = $file->move(\Config::get('plupload::plupload.upload_dir'),time().$file->getClientOriginalName());
```

Comment: Does it work without a plugin if you only use the laravel provided features? So, as I understood, basically you rename a file and would like to tell the database, that the filename has changed? Before renaming, find the database entry for your file and update this after renaming.

Comment: Yes, your right but I want multiple photo upload with preview images and allow user to edit at client side .

Comment: Anyway, you have to tell the server, that the file should be changed from old_name to new_name. Afore this, you search the entry in the db and update it. You can achieve this by using some kind of rest-controller for renaming the files to do it asynchronously without reloading your page.